# Date Looping In fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, fullcalendar

[image: This is how i want to display my dates in the calendar]**
I'm trying to add dates dynamically into a fullCalendar using a for loop**, *here is my code*

```
odoo.define('website_customs.calender', function(require) {
"use strict";


    $(function() {

       var value_1 = $('.passed_value').text();
       var objectStringArray = (new Function("return [" + value_1+ "];")());
       console.log(objectStringArray,objectStringArray[0])
       var array=[]

       for (var i in objectStringArray[0]){

       array.push(objectStringArray[0][i])

       }

       console.log("array :", array) //["2018-9-24", "2018-9-26", "2018-9-25"]
       console.log("array length",(array.length)); // 3


         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({




         for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
         events:
         [             
                        {
                        title: 'Booked',
                        start: array[j]
                        },
         ],
                                             }



    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        // event.start is already a moment.js object
        // we can apply .format()
        var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']').css('background-color', '#b72727');
     }

});

});
});
```

But i'm getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`
I tried putting the loop outside the *events* but still getting errors.

should i try some other method?any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing? there are lot of errors in your code. How can you put `for` loop inside of `Array` declaration. You should learn javascript `Array` and `Objects` first https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: now i've put the loop outside but still getting error

Comment: Still for loop is in `fullCalendar` object use `Sublime` or `vsCode` to check if your code syntax is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your event should be prepared.

```
odoo.define('website_customs.calender', function(require) {
  "use strict";
  $(function() {
    var value_1 = $('.passed_value').text();
    var objectStringArray = (new Function("return [" + value_1 + "];")());
    console.log(objectStringArray, objectStringArray[0])
    var array = [];

    for (var i in objectStringArray[0]) {
      array.push(objectStringArray[0][i])
    }

    console.log("array :", array) //["2018-9-24", "2018-9-26", "2018-9-25"]
    console.log("array length", (array.length)); // 3

    var eventsArray = []
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      eventsArray.push({ title: 'Booked', start: array[j] });
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: eventsArray,
      eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        // event.start is already a moment.js object
        // we can apply .format()
        var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']').css('background-color', '#b72727');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Accept the answer as well

Comment: But My dates are ["2018-9-24", "2018-9-26", "2018-9-25"] it is showing two events on 23rd and one event on 24th,  any idea for resolving that? thank you

Comment: Can you create js fiddle for this, don't have fullCalendar installed

Comment: missing value of `$('.passed_value').text()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181872/discussion-between-aabid-and-anand-mohan).

Comment: now i've commented that line line and given values directly, but still not coming correctly